# Why do some websites that have SSL not work but still load if using the HTTPS version? How can I avoid it if I make a website?

Tags: https, visual-glitch

Sometimes, if I go to a website, such as [this one](http://www.cnn.com/ELECTION/2010/the.basics/) through an HTTP link, it looks fine and works as apparently intended:

[image: An alright-looking HTTP webpage]

However, if you change the address to be HTTPS, the page loads without any browser warnings but looks really weird and seems broken—spacing is messed up, the colors are wrong, fonts don't load, etc.:

[image: Weird, broken HTTPS-loaded version of that same webpage]

All of this same stuff happens in both Firefox and Chrome on my computer.

**What causes this to happen? How can I avoid this if I make an HTTPS-secured website?**

Comment: I noticed this happening on a BBC website a few months ago, but can't find it currently.

Answer (score 1):

For me the browser tells you what is wrong in a warning message. `Parts of the page are not secure (such as images)`.

**What does this mean?** The developer of the site has linked some content such as CSS, JS, or images using HTTPS links and some using HTTP links.

**Why is this a problem?** Since some content is being retrieved over an insecure connection (http), it would be possible for malicious content to be injected into your browser which could then grab information which was transmitted over https. Browsers have had this warning for a very long time, but in the interest of security they have hedged their behavior on the more secure side of things now.

**What will fix this?** There is nothing we can do as consumers of the website. The owner of the site should fix the problem. If you are really interested in viewing the site and not concerned about security, you can temporarily disable this protection from the URL bar warning message in Firefox.

Comment: What causes it to look weird, though?

Answer (score 0):

As @micker explained, the page looks weird because not all of the sources are loading since their connections could not be made securely and the website's ability to load those sources are being denied by the browser for not being referenced using a secure connection.

To elaborate further. in case it's still not quite clear, a more accurate and technical explanation would be that, for styling a webpage, the Cascading Style Sheets, or CSS, is the language used to describe the presentation of a document or webpage in this case, and tells the browser how elements should be rendered on the screen. If you consider these stylesheets as sort of building blocks, where you can combine them together to define different areas on a webpage to build one masterpiece, then you would see why having multiple building blocks for a site would sound pretty normal.

To save even more time, rather than try to figure out the code for each and every stylesheet or "building block" that I want to include, I can burrow someone else's style sheet that has the properties I want and link to it as a resource instead of making or hosting the resource myself. Now if we pretend that there's a stylesheet for every font size change, font color variance, or font placement, then that means we're going to need a building block to define each of those

Now, If I am on a secure connection, then the browser ensures that connection stays secure by only connecting to other sites, or resources, which are also secure. If any of the sites containing the building blocks of CSS that I want to use but are not secure, AKA not using SSL (indicated by a lack of "s" in "http://" in their address), then the browser will prevent those connections from happening and thus prevents the resources from loading, because the browser considers it a risk to your current secure connection.

In your example's particular case, things looked fine when you entered only `http://` without the `https://` because the site you were visiting doesn't automatically force visitors to use SSL and lets you connect to it using the less secure, http protocol, which means your browser is not connecting securely to it, and therefore won't take extra steps to protect you by blocking anything outside of that since you're already on an insecure connection anyway. In which case, the browser doesn't need to prevent sources that are coming from an insecure connection or sites because in a way, your connection is already exposed so it can freely connect where it needs to and load any resources regardless if they can be transferred securely or not.

So then, when you go to the "`https://`" version of the site, there are no browser warnings because you're connecting to that site with a secure connection and unfortunately that also means that if the designer of the page had linked resources from somewhere that just didn't have an SSL connection available or didn't update the link to go to the new https:// standard, then it's going to be considered insecure and since you're on a secure connection, the browser will block those connections which means blocks those resources from being able to load, making the page load incomplete with not all of its building blocks. Build blocks that tells your screen to move all the text on the right into a panel and to have a blue font color while changing to a different font face. Those definitions defining the look and appearance didn't make it through and so those sections adopted whatever existing stylesheet is present which normally don't match with what was intended to be there.